# Length of the key to encrypt a file

Tags: c#, encryption

Many years ago I used this code to encrypt an entire file:

```
    public static void CryptFile(string sInputFilename, string sOutputFilename, string sKey)
    {
        FileStream fsInput = new FileStream(sInputFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        FileStream fsEncrypted = new FileStream(sOutputFilename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
        DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
        ICryptoTransform desencrypt = DES.CreateEncryptor();
        CryptoStream cryptostream = new CryptoStream(fsEncrypted,desencrypt,CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        byte[] bytearrayinput = new byte[fsInput.Length];
        fsInput.Read(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);
        cryptostream.Write(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);
        cryptostream.Close();
        fsInput.Close();
        fsEncrypted.Close();
    }
```

Today I tried to use it again but I always get this error:
**the specified key size is not valid for this algorithm.**
I have tried with many strings of varying length but cannot understand which is the correct length to use.

Comment: Add more information please. Include the Exception and stack trace so we know what line the exception occurs on as well as the inputs (what key size *are* you using)?

Comment: What is "sKey"? I imagine since it's DES, the key size would have to be 8 bytes. PS: This isn't a safe way to encrypt a file: DES is insecure, and you're using IV = key.

Comment: The crypto classes are quite helpful if you care to examine them whilst debugging. For instance, that `DESCryptoServiceProvider` has a `LegalKeySizes` property you could inspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct length is 8 characters, such as "12345678"